# Android onBackPressed closed app after recents menu

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, back-stack

My app will be closed after I use onBackPressed to go from ActivityB back to a Fragment in ActivityA, but only if the app has run in background (e.g. using the recents menu).

I started ActivityB like this:

```
Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class)
startActivity(b);
```

how can i prevent that the app will be closed?

**EDIT**

The launchMode of the MainActivity was set to singleinstance. Now I have set it to singleTask and all works fine.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: if have added a question.. :D

Comment: Try adding the Fragment in backstack when you commit it to container. Only a fast idea

Comment: if have added it already to backstack

Answer (score 0):

Android drops unused Activities to be memory efficient.

There are a few ways to provide this behavior:

1. This might be the most reliable
   [Parent activity manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)
2. overriding onbackPressed to start the first activity

Comment: if have already set the parent activity, but that doesn't help